# Are we allowed to post Project-like questions? If yes, should we post them on the Main Site or the Meta?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to do a project: finding hidden Minecraft recipies, that don't appear on the wikis. I want to ask users to do this toghether with me, in order to eventually find more recipies, and faster.

**However, I'm not sure if it's on topic on the main site, since it's too broad.** *But is it allowed to post it on the Meta?*

Comment: I'm sure you could figure out a way to post the *results* of this project as a question and answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden recipe"? All crafting recipes are fully documented here: minecraft.gamepedia.com/Crafting

Answer (score 9):

This wouldn't be appropriate for either the main site or meta. A project post like would just be a forum post with users discussing recipes they've found, and different ideas to try out. That's not fit for the Q&A model on Arqade, and is 
better fit to a forum.

It's not allowed on meta since meta is for asking question about Arqade itself. It's not meant to be a place to ask whatever doesn't fit into the main site.

Comment: [Meta can be a bit broader than that](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10444/should-meta-posts-regarding-the-deaths-of-figures-that-are-important-to-sffse-b#comment31239_10447) if the community desires, but I agree with your point that Meta wouldn't be the right venue for this and a forum would be much better.

Answer (score -2):

We have organized a few game-together and other community events here on meta in the past. I remember a Minecraft event or two and a certain Frozen Synapse tournament posted to meta, as well as tons of movie nights and charity events. But these were discussed and organized beforehand in chat.

Feel free to drop in there and see if you can generate some interest and if you get enough people I don't see a problem with a meta post being used to consolidate dates/times, users, track recipes, etc.

Comment: Using meta to organize community events is fine, but this isn't a community event. It's a collection of users trying to solve some game related questions, which is strictly not what meta is for. Using chat is a good idea though, and something I'd recommend.